# How do I get the rate of the schedule that triggered a lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I have multiple event schedules attached to a single lambda:

```
  Events:
    1minute:
      Type: Schedule
      Properties:
        Schedule: rate(1 minute)
    2minute:
      Type: Schedule
      Properties:
        Schedule: rate(2 minutes)
    etc...
```

The lambda does different things based on the schedule. The logic is super simple so it's much simpler to attach multiple schedules to the same function instead of creating multiple separate functions.

I can parse the event name from the event and use that to determine what the schedule is.

Creating them with the sam template though means they wind up having names like:

```
myapp-myfunction2minutes-ABC123XDJXKDF
```

I still want them to be created dynamically. I don't want to set static names because that would prevent multiple stacks from existing simultaneously and I want them to be fully namespaced and isolated.

I can certainly parse myapp-myfunction2minutes-ABC123XDJXKDF because it's predictable enough, but it would be even better if I could add some other field with arbitrary metadata so I would not have to do any string parsing. Is this supported?

### Edit

Configuring this in a template looks like this:

```
  Events:
    1minute:
      Type: Schedule
      Input: '{"Key": "Value1"}'
      Properties:
        Schedule: rate(1 minute)
    2minute:
      Type: Schedule
      Input: '{"Key": "Value2"}'
      Properties:
        Schedule: rate(2 minutes)
    etc...
```

Then "Input" replaces the *entire* event sent to the lambda. So in the function (if python) can access like `event["Key"]`.

Another thing that tripped me up was that Input seems to be directly connected to the specific lambda it's created under. In testing I deployed the stack with these events configured with inputs, then to do a quick test I attached one of the events (the CloudWatch rule) to a *different* lambda to try and read the event it created. Doing that didn't work, the other lambda was triggered on the schedule but the event object sent to it didn't have the Input- it was a regular CloudWatch schedule event object.

Comment: Can you add that "metadata" to lambda [tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-tags)?

Comment: not sure i understand. the metadata needs to be attached to the event itself and I only have one instance of the lambda. I _could_ create 5+ lambdas and attach a diff event to each one and pass a diff env var value to each one but thats an ugly way to handle this

Comment: In that case, check John's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you want to know which schedule triggered the Lambda function. Well, you actually asked for the rate, but hopefully knowing which schedule triggered it will be just as good.

When you add the Lambda trigger, you can specify a **Constant**, which will be passed through the `event`. You can use this to trigger the desired behaviour.

[image: CloudWatch Events rule]

Comment: oh man is that a "Property" ? I cant find that here, maybe this is the wrong resource type? SAM is wrapping/simplifying this piece so need to be supported by SAM too: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html. not sure how to wire up a constant in the sam template

Comment: Worst case you could go in and manually add the constant to the schedule.

Comment: Within CloudFormation, the Rule has a `AWS::Events::Rule Target`, which contains an `Input` field. You can hopefully put the identifier in there.

Comment: maybe im confused about how this works but I added `Input: '{"Key": "Value"}'` and that isnt getting added to the actual event that is sent to the lambda at all

Comment: this is all I see in the event: `{'account': '11111111',
'detail': {},
'detail-type': 'Scheduled Event',
'id': '1111111-1111-1111-1111-1111111',
'region': 'us-east-1',
'resources': ['arn:aws:events:us-east-1:11111111:rule/myapp1minute-SDFSDF2342342'],
'source': 'aws.events',
'time': '2020-05-28T02:03:46Z',
'version': '0'}`

Comment: I added `{"Key":"foobar"}` as my Constant, and it appeared in the event. In fact, it was the _only_ contents of the `event`. I printed `event` from the function, and it appeared in the debug log.